# Laravel raw sum query to laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a laravel query builder from the following raw query:

```
SELECT establishments.*, SUM(invoice_rows.total_price) as total_price_sum 
FROM `establishments` 
JOIN invoices on invoices.establishment_id = establishments.id 
JOIN invoice_rows ON invoice_rows.invoice_id = invoices.id 
WHERE invoice_rows.invoice_article_group_id = 11 
GROUP BY establishments.id 
ORDER BY total_price_sum DESC
```

I have tried different methods such as: with, whereHas and withCount but I can't seem to create the correct laravel query builder for the raw query.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? The `where` clause should be sufficient since you're selecting from a single query. One thing to note is that you'll need to still use a `DB::raw` for the SUM portion of the select, since the `sum()` command just returns a single sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) and [Raw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries) in Laravel doc ..

your query should be like this:

```
   $values=DB::table('establishments')->select(['establishments.id',
            DB::raw('SUM(invoice_rows.total_price) as total_price_sum')])
            ->join('invoices','invoices.establishment_id','=','establishments.id')
            ->join('invoice_rows','invoice_rows.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
            ->where('invoice_rows.invoice_article_group_id',11)
            ->groupBy('establishments.id')
            ->orderByDesc('total_price_sum')->get();
```

please note that you cant select `establishments.*` and then group by only `establishments.id`

Comment: I tried to create a query builder using the laravel model and not using DB, is that possible at all?

Comment: yes, but if you want that, you should have share your models

Comment: any way,  in your case ,the only difference is :  Establishment::  instead of    DB::table('establishments')

Comment: fair enough, but that wouldn't be possible without using the raw query for the sum right?

Comment: yes, sum is not supported directly, you should use DB::raw to get it